# Batch file "more than one variable"

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have a code for a game I'd like to make (batch file).
How can I have a sensing line of code that sees if a variable is greater than one? In this example, the variable is `%pot%`.

```
if %pot% == 0 goto nopots1
if %pot% ==
```

So basically, if I have 0 pots, I go to a different screen that tells me I have no pots. I want to make the code so that if I have 1 or more pots, I go to a different screen. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you read the help file for the IF command you could have answered your own inquiry.

Comment: I hadn't known how to get to that before @Magoo answered my question :)

Comment: If you Google Search: **batch file if command** the very first link it finds is this: https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: I'm sorry I offended you. I apologize for my lack of knowledge for that site. I will definitely be using it. Thanks.

Comment: Teach a man to fish. I live by that philosophy. Bookmark that site. Has all the commands you can use in a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %pots% gtr 0 ...
```

`if` supports `equ` `gtr` `lss` `neq` `geq` and `leq` as well as `==`; also `/i` for case-insensitivity.

See `if /?` from the prompt for more info.

Comment: Fixed it perfectly. I get the prompt from the normal cmd, correct? I'd accept your answer, but I have to wait 8 minutes. I'll accept it when I can, thanks.

Comment: Just so. Serious batchers simply create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` on the desktop...

Comment: @Magoo - I've got it pinned to my taskbar :)

Comment: Accepted, by the way.